# Cannot connect localhost to ropsten testnet via infura

Tags: web3js

I want to connet my meteor localhost to ropsten testnet.
Therefore i have a lib.js with the connecting commands:

`//var Web3 = require('web3');
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://ropsten.infura.io/..."));

    if(!web3.isConnected())
        console.log("not connected");
    else
        console.log("connected");
}`

A time out msg appears. I read about the 
`var Web3 = require('web3');`
But when i add this line i also get a error msg for missing modules.
How can i get this run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [Web3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3), and add the

> var Web3 = require('web3');

Comment: it solved the problem, but now i get web3.isConnected is not a function. I got the 1.0.0 beta version of web3

Comment: Please remove your private infura key from your last comment.
Also, try 
if( false === web3.isConnected())

Comment: also i added console.log(web3.currentprovider) after new web3 and i get <code>HttpProvider {host: "ropsten.infura.io/...";, timeout: 0, connected: false} connected : false host : "ropsten.infura.io/..."; timeout : 0 proto : Object</code>

Comment: so looks like ropsten won't let you connect ?